# How to use JPEG2000 in SDL?

Tags: sdl, jpeg2000, sdl-image

I found that `JPEG2000` has an alpha channel, and I want to change `PNG` format to `JPEG2000` in my project which is based on `SDL 2.0.3` and `SDL_Image`. Is it possible to use `JPEG2000` in `SDL`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no support for JPEG2000 in stock SDL_Image. What you can do is find the necessary libraries/headers and implement this directly, maybe using SDL_Image to load your PNGs into surfaces/textures and then writing your own methods for exporting to JPEG2000.

Comment: It is possible to use library `openJPEG` and to add necessary functionality to `SDL_Image`. But I can't do it now. Perhaps someone (or I) will do it in the future.

Comment: You shouldn't have to modify `SDL_Image` at all, I meant that you could write your own wrapper for the relevant jpeg library to interface with your project. I recently had to do this with giflib to support animated GIF images in my SDL app.